# Смартфон в режиме разработчика остаётся неопределяемый

Tags: android

Смартфон POSH HD E600 ...нет русского языка...программа морелокале установлена,на компьютере стоит ADB ...в режиме adb deveces компьютер не определяет  смартфон.режим разработчика включён.Стоит андроид 4.4.2.При подключении комп видит все папки.Чего ему не хватает...может есть способ как то установить русский язык ещё?

Comment: Как этот вопрос относится к теме данного сайта?

Comment: Попробуйте поставить гугловые драйвера и сменить на девайсе способо подключения по USB